# iPhone 7 and 7 Plus wallpapers in iOS 10

Tags: ios, wallpaper, iphone

On apple.com some variations of this wallpaper are shown on iPhone 7 and 7 Plus screens:

[image]

I can't find them on my iPhone 7 (iOS 10.0.2). Are they available exclusively for 7 Plus?

Here the same question: https://discussions.apple.com/message/30744677#30744677 (but no answer).

Comment: Did you setup your iPhone 7 as 'new' or from a backup?  EDIT: I just found out that these wallpapers are not included on the new iPhone or in iOS 10.  It's just for advertising the screen image.

Comment: I see there's now a bounty on this question but I'm not sure how anyone can successfully answer it.  There won't be anything on Apple's site about something **not** included in the OS and it's well known, now, that there's 3rd-party apps and images available to replicate these wallpapers.  So what exactly is this bounty for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These wallpapers (as well as new emoji) will probably be available with iOS 10.2. At least they are available with 10.2 beta 1.

Comment: Can you supply some support for this?  I'd like to be able to see it from an Apple site, if possible.

Comment: It's from 10.2 beta 1. Install it and you'll see.

Comment: You should update your answer with the source of the info.  That way, people who have the same question will know how reliable the answer is.  For instance, sometimes items are pulled from beta releases and they don't make the GM release.  Someone not knowing that will think their 10.2 install is not working because they don't see {insert feature here}.

Answer (score 0):

They are not available by default but you can find them online [here.](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/09/download-all-new-iphone-7-wallpapers.html)

Answer (score 0):

No. These wallpapers are just for advertising the iPhone 7 / 7 Plus. These wallpapers will not be available in the Settings > Wallpapers > Stills . As Tom S said, You can download these full resolution [here](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/09/download-all-new-iphone-7-wallpapers.html). Just Tap and Hold on the image and select save to camera role / save to photos. after that, you can go to Settings > Wallpapers > choose new Wallpaper. you should be able to see "All photos". In that, just select the preferred Image, A preview screen will open. There, turn on perspective zoom, as it give an active felling to the wallpaper, or turn it off if you want to conserve more battery.